# stack cylinder to get max surface area

Tags: algorithm

I have to stack the cylinders such that I get the largest surface area. 
The surface area is the visible part of the stacked cylinder.
I have to select k cylinders from given n cylinder to form the stack.

n <= 1000. And k is less than n. Cylinders can be placed regardless of radius (we can place a wider cylinder on top of a narrower one). Just the visible surface area should be maximum. (We consider the base of the lowest cylinder hidden.)

My approach was to first calculate the surface area of all the cylinder and sort them. Then with the radius and height, I can create another list which would be sorted based on radius and height. But, this approach fails to get the largest surface area of the selected cylinder in some cases.

How can I approach this problem in a different way?

Comment: What's the maximum value for `n`?

Comment: 1000. And k is less than n.

Comment: Can cylinders be placed regardless of their relative radius or must narrower cylinders be placed on wider ones?

Comment: Regardless of radius. Just the visible surface area should be maximum

Comment: Assuming the answer to the previous comment is that narrower cylinders must be placed on wider cylinders, then the subproblems can be expressed as radius and remaining-k. If cylinders can be placed regardless of radius, then alternating between large and small radius is obviously desirable, but I don't see any easy way to express the subproblems.

Comment: Unrelated, it's mathematically possible to envision a solid with finite volume but infinite surface area. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffUnNaQTfZE

Comment: The heights of the cylinders are not relevant; only the radii (diameters) matter.  You should put the smallest cylinder between the two biggest cylinders; the second smallest should be between the biggest and the third biggest; and so on.  That's a little easier to conceive than to code, I suspect.  Each cylinder can be between two others, except for those at the ends.  And generally, you want alternating big and small, but you'd need to think carefully about degenerate cases (2, 3, even 4 might be degenerate), etc.  And proving that this gives the maximum might be another issue.

Comment: The heights of the cylinders are very relevant since the side area of the cylinder is proportional to the height. For example, given `n=5` and `k=3`, and cylinders {6,10}, {6,10}, {1,10}, {1,10}, {2,1000000}, you're definitely going to choose the cylinder with radius 2.

Comment: Do we count the surface area of the base of the lowest cylinder?

Comment: No, since it’s not visible

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we will alternate relative radii such that narrower cylinders will be between wider cylinders so as to minimise the covered top and base surface areas. Then to calculate the total surface area, we subtract only the doubled top and bottom surface areas of the narrower cylinders.

If we guarantee choosing narrower cylinders in between, however, the order of the chosen cylinders, other than the bottom, does not matter (aside from obliging the narrower-in-between restriction). This is because the only affecting variables are which cylinders are chosen.

Furthermore, for every selection of cylinders, there's at least one obvious optimal arrangement: place the largest narrow cylinder, the (larger) median, on the bottom and alternate. We are guaranteed to subtract from the total surface area, only the lowest of the horizontal surface areas in our chosen list.

```
Given horizontal surface areas:
1 2 3 4 5

3 1 5 2 4 is the same as 
3 2 5 1 4 but larger than
2 4 3 5 1 because in the former
we subtract 3 + 4*2 + 4*1 from the
total, whereas in the latter, we
subtract 3*2 + 4*3 + 2*1
```

Given `k` cylinders, an optimal arrangement will subtract the lowest `k/2` doubled horizontal surface areas, except the (larger) median for which only one horizontal surface is subtracted.

If we add another cylinder, `x`, with a not-smaller radius than all the others, then we can either

```
(1) replace a cylinder, y, that has a radius
    greater than the (larger) median
    In this case, we increase the
    total surface area by
      total_area(x) - total_area(y)
```

or

```
(2) replace a cylinder, y, that has a radius
    lower than or equal to the (larger) median, m,
    in which case the median will
    shift to the next higher radius, m1.

    If we're replacing m, we'll add
    total_area(x)
    - (total_area(m) - horizontal_area(m)) // removed
    - horizontal_area(m1) // goes to bottom

    otherwise, we will add
      total_area(x)
      - 3*horizontal_area(m) // no longer on bottom
      - horizontal_area(m1) // goes to bottom
      + 4*horizontal_area(y) - vertical_area(y) // removed
```

If this kind of greedy priority queue works, we could have an O(nk) time routine by first sorting by ascending radius and trying all elements in the current queue as candidates for replacement as we iterate over the list. Otherwise, perhaps we can use the information here towards another optimisation.

#### Update

I'd like to include comments by user3386109 (from below this answer), which may further refine this direction:

- Another way to look at the problem for the case where k is odd. The cylinder with the median radius goes on the bottom. Cylinders wider than the median add both top and bottom area. The median cylinder adds its top area. Cylinders narrower than the median subtract top and bottom area. So the total horizontal area in the example (`3 1 4 2 5`) is (5+5)+(4+4)+(3)-(2+2)-(1+1) = 15
- When replacing cylinders, there are three possibilities: 1) replace the median, 2A) replace a wide cylinder with another wide cylinder, 2B) replace a narrow cylinder with another narrow cylinder. In case 2A, remove the wide cylinder that has minimum total area (side+top+bottom). In case 2B, remove the narrow cylinder that has minimum subtractive area (side-top-bottom).
- In general, I think the approach proposed in this answer is the correct approach. Take the first k cylinders, and arrange them. Then consider whether each new cylinder can be used to improve the total area, replacing one of the existing cylinders.

Comment: In the example, I'm pretty sure the 5 should be on top, since the entire horizontal area of the top cylinder is visible. So the order from bottom to top would be 3,2,4,1,5.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for thinking and commenting. First, we total the complete surface areas. Now the ones to subtract are only dictated by the narrower cylinders (with your choice, also the bottom of 3). For the case you chose, 3 2 4 1 5, we subtract (3 + 4*2 + 4*1) = 15. For the case I chose, 2 4 1 5 3, we subtract (3*2 + 4*1 + 2*3) = 16. Your choice was better (which points to the bottom playing a role) but notice that it's only dependent on the bottom and the narrower ones in between. We could arbitrarily switch 1 and 2 or 4 and 5 in your example and end up with the same result.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, switching 1 and 2 or 4 and 5 makes no difference.

Comment: @user3386109 for that reason, I think there are overlapping subproblems to exploit, although I'm not sure yet how to formulate it.

Comment: @user3386109 we also know that whatever `k` we choose, the `k/2` cylinders (+- 1 as you showed) with the smallest radii will end up in between and dictate most if not all the surface area to subtract.

Comment: I took your observations and ideas a few steps further in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360664/1210053). Thanks for sharing them. Feel free to suggest any additions or changes.

Comment: Another way to look at the problem for the case where `k` is odd. The cylinder with the median radius goes on the bottom. Cylinders wider than the median add both top and bottom area. The median cylinder adds its top area. Cylinders narrower than the median subtract top and bottom area. So the total horizontal area in the example is `(5+5)+(4+4)+(3)-(2+2)-(1+1) = 15`.

Comment: When replacing cylinders, there are three possibilities: 1) replace the median, 2A) replace a wide cylinder with another wide cylinder, 2B) replace a narrow cylinder with another narrow cylinder. In case 2A, remove the wide cylinder that has minimum total area (side+top+bottom). In case 2B, remove the narrow cylinder that has minimum subtractive area (side-top-bottom).

Comment: In general, I think the approach proposed in this answer is the correct approach. Take the first `k` cylinders, and arrange them. Then consider whether each new cylinder can be used to improve the total area, replacing one of the existing cylinders.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you again for thinking and commenting. I included your comments in the updated answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I enjoyed collaborating with you on this problem. You had some important insights that I would have missed on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming: Cylinders with a bigger radius, cannot be stacked on a cylinder with a smaller radius, you first need to sort them by radius.

Think about adding on cylinder (C1) on top of the other (C2). The top surface area of C1 gets covered by the bottom surface area of C2. As the same time the top of C2 equals its bottom. So in the decision making of what cylinder to take we only need to take into account the side surface area.

There is one exception: for the lowest cylinder its top surface area needs to be taken into account too!

We want on the bottom the cylinder with the biggest surface area and still have k cylinders on top of this. So we need to select the out of the sorted cylinders (total - k + 1) the one with the biggest total surface area, this becomes the bottom.
Next we need to take the k-1 cylinders in order of biggest side area, this is your answer.

Example below: Out of 10 cylinders take 4.

Select the bottom cylinder out of the 7 cylinders with biggest radius, it is the cylinder with the biggest total surface area (1). Now take the 3 with the biggest Side area (2,3 & 4). Stack the cylinders!

[image]

In C# code:

```
    public class Cylinder
    {
        private double radius, height;
        public Cylinder(double Radius, double Height)
        {
            radius = Radius;
            height = Height;
        }
        public double Radius { get { return radius; } }
        public double Height { get{return height; } }

        public double SideArea { get { return radius * height * Math.PI; } }
        public double TotalArea { get { return SideArea + Math.PI * radius * radius; } }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Cylinder> stack = new List<Cylinder>();
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(2, 356));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(23, 0.25));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(3, 8));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(10, 2));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(22, 3));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(4, 40));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(2.5, 2));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(21, 2));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(3.5, 32));
            stack.Add(new Cylinder(7, 1));

            List<Cylinder> orderedStack = stack.OrderByDescending(c => c.Radius).ThenByDescending(c=>c.Height).ToList();

            int k = 4;
            Cylinder Bottom = orderedStack.Take(orderedStack.Count + 1 - k).OrderByDescending(c => c.TotalArea).First();
            int index = orderedStack.IndexOf(Bottom);

            List<Cylinder> stackedCylinders = orderedStack.Skip(index + 1).OrderByDescending(c => c.SideArea).Take(k - 1).OrderByDescending(c=>c.Radius).ToList();

            stackedCylinders.Insert(0,Bottom);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It selects 100, 100 as bottom and then takes 25, 50. You have a total of 250.

Comment: No, we only add the side because the top is not relevant as in my text. Only for the bottom the top is relevant.

Comment: When you stack a cylinder you cover also the top area of the previous cylinder. so it equals each other out.

Comment: @Aldert That assumes that the largest radius is on the bottom, and the cylinders are stacked with narrower cylinders on top of wider cylinders. But in the comments, the OP stated that cylinders can be stacked in any order, regardless of radius.

Comment: How about this example (side-area, top-area): [(100,100), (30,100), (20,50)], k = 3 ? According to your idea, they are already in order of selection so the large base area of (30,100) would completely cover (100,100). But if we place the narrower (20, 50) in the middle, both top and bottom cylinders would only have a partially covered horizontal surface, yielding more in total.

Comment: How can you put a narrow cylinder in the middle? See first sentence of my answer: Cylinders with a bigger radius, cannot be stacked on a cylinder with a smaller radius, you first need to sort them by radius. I believe the problem definition is different then.

Comment: OP stated that - look at the first four comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds upon גלעד ברקן's answer. So, if you like this answer, please also upvote his.

Let's assume we already know the `k` cylinders that we are going to use. Then, for a given order, we can calculate the total visible surface area as:

```
            k                                           k-1
A_visible = Σ  A_(total,i) - A_(baseArea, bottomMost) -  Σ  A_(hidden,i)
           i=0                                          i=0
```

`A_(total,i)` is the total surface area of cylinder `i`, `A_(hidden,i)` is the surface area that is hidden due to occlusion at interface `i` (we have one less interfaces than cylinders), and `A_(baseArea, bottomMost)` is the base area (of the top and bottom bases) of the bottom-most cylinder. The hidden surface is

```
A_(hidden,i) = 2 * min(A_(base,i), A_(base,i+1))
```

`A_(base,i)` is the base area of cylinder `i`. That is, the smaller base area at an interface is hidden from both cylinders.

So, if we want to maximize for a known set of cylinders

```
                    k                                                k-1
max A_visible = max Σ  A_(total,i) - min[ A_(baseArea, bottomMost) +  Σ  2 * min(A_(base,i), A_(base,i+1)) ]
                   i=0                                               i=0
```

then we can drop the first term and simply minimize the second term. Hence, we want to find an order where the summed minimum base area of each interface plus the bottom-most hidden surface is minimal. As גלעד ברקן already pointed out, this can be minimized by alternating between wide and narrow cylinders. However, we still don't know if the bottom-most cylinder is a wide or narrow one. Let us consider both cases for even and odd `k`:

```
          k=7         |         k=8
   case A     case B  |  case C     case D
                      |
7                     |    xxx     xxxxxxxx
6  xxxxxxxx    xxx    |  xxxxxxx      xxx
5    xxx      xxxxxx  |    xxx       xxxxx
4   xxxxx       xx    |  xxxxxxx      xx
3    xx       xxxxx   |    xx      xxxxxxx
2  xxxxxxx     xxx    |  xxxxxx      xxx
1    xxx     xxxxxxx  |   xxx      xxxxxx
0  xxxxxxx      xx    | xxxxxxxx      xx
---------------------------------------------
```

The deductible areas for the four cases are (`Ai` stands for `A_(base,i)`):

```
case A:     A0 + 4 * (A1 + A3 + A5)
case B: 3 * A0 + 4 * (A2 + A4)      + 2 * A6
case C:     A0 + 4 * (A1 + A3 + A5) + 2 * A7
case D: 3 * A0 + 4 * (A2 + A4 + A6)
```

In each of these cases, we want to find an assignment that results in the minimum deductible area. Hence, we order the available cylinders by their base area and start assigning the smallest ones to the slots with factor 4, the next one to the slot with factor 3 and so on. We get the following coefficients for the sequence of ordered base areas `Bi` (`B0 <= B1 <= B2 ...`):

```
    case A  case B  |  case C  case D
B0     4       4    |     4       4
B1     4       4    |     4       4
B2     4       3    |     4       4
B3     1       2    |     2       3
B4                  |     1
```

Let us compare the two cases for odd `k`

```
          case A < case B
<=>  4 * B2 + B3 < 3 * B2 + 2 * B3
<=>           B2 < B3
```

This is always the case since the `Bi` are ordered. Hence, case A is always the optimum for odd `k`. We have `(k - 1)/2` coefficients of `4` and one coefficient of `1`.

Now the even cases:

```
         case C < case D
<=> 2 * B3 + B4 < 3 * B3
<=>          B4 < B3
```

This is never the case. Hence, case `D` is always the optimum for even `k` with `k / 2 - 1` coefficients of `4` and one coefficient of `3`.

So, we have a partitioning of our cylinders into narrow cylinders, wide cylinders, and the middle cylinder (which will be the bottom cylinder). Then, the maximum visible area is (the following is for odd `k`; for even `k` replace the last coefficient)

```
                k               
max A_visible = Σ  A_(total,i) - A_(base,middle) -     Σ      4 * A_(base,j)
               i=0                                 j ∈ narrow
```

Now, we want to find what `k` cylinders to choose. Let us re-write above equation such that the sums go over separate cylinder ranges:

```
max A_visible =    Σ    A_(total,j) + A_(total,middle) - A_(base,middle) +       Σ      [A_(total,j) - 4 * A_(base,j)]
                j ∈ wide                                                    j ∈ narrow
```

Now, how do we find the cylinders? It is all about the middle element. So let us first sort the `n` cylinders by their base areas. If we know the middle element, then the cylinders in the narrow set must be left of the middle element, and the cylinders in the wide set must be right of it. And to find the actual cylinders, we simply find the set that maximizes the sum of `A_(total,j)` (for the wide set) or `A_(total,j) - 4 * A(base,j)` (for the narrow set).

We consider each element as the middle element and find the maximum value. This can be done incrementally by two subsequent traversals from both sides. For the first traversal, initialize the middle element such that the narrow set will have exactly the required number of entries. Then, iteratively push the middle element further and check if replacing any of the existing entries with the new entry will increase the area (evaluate `A_(total,j) - 4 * A_(baseArea, j)` and keep the largest elements in a heap of correct size). Store the maximum per each middle element in a list (i.e., list entry 6 will keep the maximum area if we assume that element 6 is the middle element). Then, do the same thing from the other side for the wide set (evaluate `A_(total, j)` only) and generate a second list. Finally, we need to find the correct middle element. For this, we traverse both lists at the same time and find the maximum of `narrowList[i] + A(total,i) - A_(base,i) + wideList[i]`. This is your final result. Again, for even `k`, you need to adapt the coefficient of the middle element.

### Implementation

Here is some example C++ code. The time complexity of the algorithm is *O(n log n)*, which can be reduced to *O(n log k)* if a linear sorting algorithm is used or if the cylinders are already sorted.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Cylinder
{
    double baseArea, totalArea;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Cylinder& c)
{
    return stream << "(" << c.baseArea << ", " << c.totalArea << ")";
}

typedef std::pair<double, int> MaxEntry; //holds pairs of contributed area and cylinder index
typedef std::priority_queue<MaxEntry, std::vector<MaxEntry>, std::greater<MaxEntry>> MaxElementsQueue;

//Calculates the maximum contributing area for a set of elementsInSet cylinders in the range [startIndex, endIndex] (both inclusive).
//  areaFunction(i): calculates the contributing area for cylinder i
//  reportAreaCallback(i, area, elements): reports the maximum area for a set with cylinders in the range [startIndex, i - direction] (i is the middle element)
void calculateMaxAreas(int startIndex, int endIndex, int direction, int elementsInSet, std::function<double(int)>&& areaFunction, std::function<void(int, double, const MaxElementsQueue& elements)>&& reportAreaCallback)
{   
    MaxElementsQueue maxElements;
    double totalSetArea = 0;
    //initialize the queue with elementsInSet elements
    int firstMiddleElement = startIndex + direction * elementsInSet;
    for (int i = startIndex; i * direction < firstMiddleElement * direction; i += direction)
    {
        double area = areaFunction(i);
        maxElements.push(std::make_pair(area, i));
        totalSetArea += area;
    }
    reportAreaCallback(firstMiddleElement, totalSetArea, maxElements);
    for (int i = firstMiddleElement + direction; i * direction <= endIndex * direction + 1; i += direction)
    {
        //try to replace the cylinder with smallest contribution with another cylinder
        double area = areaFunction(i - direction);
        auto& smallestEntry = maxElements.top();
        if (area > smallestEntry.first)
        {
            totalSetArea -= smallestEntry.first;
            maxElements.pop();
            maxElements.push(std::make_pair(area, i - 1));
            totalSetArea += area;
        }
        reportAreaCallback(i, totalSetArea, maxElements);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Input
    int k = 3;
    std::vector<Cylinder> availableCylinders;
    availableCylinders.push_back({ 20, 100 });
    availableCylinders.push_back({ 30, 70 });
    availableCylinders.push_back({ 40, 120 });
    availableCylinders.push_back({ 50, 180 });

    //Derived information
    int narrowCylinders, wideCylinders, middleCylinderCoefficient;
    if (k % 2 == 0) //k is even
    {
        narrowCylinders = k / 2 - 1;
        middleCylinderCoefficient = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        narrowCylinders = (k - 1) / 2;
        middleCylinderCoefficient = 1;
    }
    wideCylinders = k - 1 - narrowCylinders;

    //calculate area lists for narrow set and wide set
    //we ignore some indices to make the code more readable
    std::vector<double> narrowCylinderSetAreas(availableCylinders.size());
    std::vector<double> wideCylinderSetAreas(availableCylinders.size());

    //sort cylinders by base area
    std::sort(availableCylinders.begin(), availableCylinders.end(),
        [](const Cylinder& left, const Cylinder& right) { return left.baseArea < right.baseArea; });

    //calculate narrow set areas
    auto narrowAreaFunction = [&](int i) { return availableCylinders[i].totalArea - 4 * availableCylinders[i].baseArea; };
    calculateMaxAreas(0, availableCylinders.size() - 1 - wideCylinders - 1, 1, narrowCylinders,
        narrowAreaFunction, 
        [&](int i, double area, const MaxElementsQueue& queue) { narrowCylinderSetAreas[i] = area; });

    //calculate wide set areas
    auto wideAreaFunction = [&](int i) { return availableCylinders[i].totalArea; };
    calculateMaxAreas(availableCylinders.size() - 1, narrowCylinders + 1, -1, wideCylinders,
        wideAreaFunction,
        [&](int i, double area, const MaxElementsQueue& queue) { wideCylinderSetAreas[i] = area; });    

    //now find the optimal middle cylinder
    double maxArea = -1;
    int maxAreaIndex;
    for (int i = narrowCylinders; i < availableCylinders.size() - wideCylinders; ++i)
    {
        double totalArea = wideCylinderSetAreas[i] + availableCylinders[i].totalArea - middleCylinderCoefficient * availableCylinders[i].baseArea + narrowCylinderSetAreas[i];
        if (totalArea > maxArea)
        {
            maxArea = totalArea;
            maxAreaIndex = i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Maximum visible area: " << maxArea << " with bottom cylinder " << availableCylinders[maxAreaIndex] << std::endl;

    //reconstruct the elements in the wide and narrow sets
    calculateMaxAreas(0, maxAreaIndex - 1, 1, narrowCylinders, narrowAreaFunction, 
        [&](int i, double area, const MaxElementsQueue& elements)
    {
        if (i == maxAreaIndex)
        {
            std::cout << "Cylinders in narrow set: ";
            auto elementsCopy = elements;
            while (!elementsCopy.empty())
            {
                std::cout << availableCylinders[elementsCopy.top().second] << " ";
                elementsCopy.pop();
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    });

    calculateMaxAreas(availableCylinders.size() - 1, maxAreaIndex + 1, -1, wideCylinders, wideAreaFunction,
        [&](int i, double area, const MaxElementsQueue& elements)
    {
        if (i == maxAreaIndex)
        {
            std::cout << "Cylinders in wide set: ";
            auto elementsCopy = elements;
            while (!elementsCopy.empty())
            {
                std::cout << availableCylinders[elementsCopy.top().second] << " ";
                elementsCopy.pop();
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    });
}
```

Sample output:

```
Maximum visible area: 280 with bottom cylinder (40, 120)
Cylinders in narrow set: (20, 100)
Cylinders in wide set: (50, 180)
```

Comment: Nice. I like the equations and the idea of the separating index. How do you address the choice of bottom? Please the comments under my answer (they refer to an earlier edit). The bottom affects your equations - if it's base is smaller than the next cylinder's, we'd subtract 3 rather 4 times its base area. And if it's larger, we'd subtract 1 times its base area.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Hm.. I assumed that the bottom-most surface is visible (the stack will float in space). I don't know if this is how the problem is intended. Good point. The solution will be similar, though. It will just not have the simple partitioning into small and large cylinders, but into three groups (similar as for even `k`). And by that assumption, the lowest cylinder is also always larger than the next one. Let's see if we can get some clarification from the OP.

Comment: Ha! Floating in space. I didn't think of it :)

Comment: Not sure the concepts of top and bottom apply in space, though :)

Comment: Op just clarified in the comments - it's as I thought.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I updated the answer. The solution is surprisingly structured. Thanks for pointing out the flaw in my initial solution.